# How fix my mouse and keyboard from disconnecting. is it the driver or the usb?

Tags: usb, drivers, keyboard, mouse, hid

I am using a HID-compliant mouse and HID keyboard and they keep disconnecting. I tried every thing like reinstalling them, using msconfig and making a new `INFCACHE.1` folder. But nothing works. Do I need a new mouse and keyboard?

Please help me. It's driving me insane.

Comment: Easy trick to rule out hardware issues : boot on a GNU/Linux LiveCD and see if the problem still occurs. If it doesn't, it's definitely a software issue on the Windows side and you should try updating your USB controller's driver (usually bundled with the chipset's drivers), otherwise look for a hardware issue in your kb/mouse or a faulty USB controller/motherboard.

Comment: If you do not have Linux Live CD, try to connect your keyboard and mouse to some other computer see if the same happens

Comment: i don't have a another computer

Comment: or a linux live cd

Comment: also i used drive booster and they are up to date and kinda having the same problem